# Implementing switch case + if else conditions with matrix

Tags: matrix, java-6

I have got 2 enums,

```
public enum CASES { CASE1, CASE2, CASE3, CASE4 };
```

Now I have to implement a logic condition like below,

```
private CASES getCondition(final CASES firstLevel, final CASES secondLevel){
 Switch(firstLevel) {
      case CASE1: 
            if(secondLevel == CASES.CASE1)
              return CASES.CASE1;
            else if(secondLevel == CASES.CASE2)
              return CASES.CASE1;
            else if(secondLevel == CASES.CASE3)
              return CASES.CASE4;
            else 
              return CASE3;
      case CASE2: 
              // Some combination logic as above;
      case CASE3: 
              // Some combination logic as above;
      case CASE4: 
              // Some combination logic as above;
       }

}
```

Since this condition is going too complex, i would like to implement using matrix.

- Could any one suggest the best way to implement using matrix?
- Is it possible to use enums as indexes?
- Will implementation using EnumMap of EnumMap is a possible solution?
- Also, is there any existing solution for this kind of logic implementations?

Please help.